# Inferring multiple generics of extended class in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Had a similar scenario at work (where it turns out I didn't really need to solve it and was fine to use a simpler approach overall), but this really bugged me, and I wasn't able to find anyone else with the same kind of issue, where TypeScript infers generics from an extended class only when there's 1 generic in the base class definition, or when the instance is created from the base class + generics (or converted to it using `as`).

Here's the initial (made up) scenario (works):

```js
class Employee<ProfessionInfo> {
  id: number
  name: string
  professionInfo: ProfessionInfo
}

function extractProfessionInfo<ProfessionInfo>(employee: Employee<ProfessionInfo>) {
  return employee.professionInfo;
}

// ----

interface ITInfo {
  languages: string[]
}

class ITEmployee extends Employee<ITInfo> {

}


const jane = new Employee<ITInfo>();
const john = new ITEmployee();

extractProfessionInfo(jane); // return type is ITInfo
extractProfessionInfo(john); // return type is ITInfo
```

But then if you have to extend the base class by adding a second generic, you get a different behavior:

```js
class Employee<ProfessionInfo, RoleInfo> {
  id: number
  name: string
  professionInfo: ProfessionInfo & RoleInfo
}

function extractProfessionInfo<RegionalInfo, RoleInfo>(employee: Employee<RegionalInfo, RoleInfo>) {
  return employee.professionInfo;
}

// ----

interface ITInfo {
  languages: string[]
}

interface ManagerInfo {
  departmentId: number
}

class ITManagerEmployee extends Employee<ITInfo, ManagerInfo> {

}


const jane = new Employee<ITInfo, ManagerInfo>();
const john = new ITManagerEmployee();
const joey = new ITManagerEmployee() as Employee<ITInfo, ManagerInfo>();

extractProfessionInfo(jane); // return type is ITInfo & ManagerInfo
extractProfessionInfo(john); // return type is unknown (and all generics for the function are inferred as unknown)
extractProfessionInfo(joey); // return type is ITInfo & ManagerInfo
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Or is my only option to cast my extended class like in my last employee instance above?

Comment: There's no good way to infer from an intersection like that.  If your types only ever show up in intersections then you need one type parameter, not two, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mba24N).  If that meets your needs I'll write up an answer explaining; if it doesn't, please [edit] to show code that only works properly if you have two type params instead of one.